Assigning a dynamic name to a plot in R?
createMap <- function(df1) {

map <- get_googlemap(center="Milwaukee") %>% ggmap()+
    stat_density2d(data=df1, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, fill=..density..),geom='tile', contour=F, alpha=.5)+
labs(fill="seizure density")+
scale_fill_viridis(option="inferno")

return map
}

createMap(my_df)

I want to call this function to return a plot that is named: map_my_df (i.e. the name of the dataset is included in the name).  In other words, I want to name the plot dynamically (not the plot tile, I mean the actual variable name of the plot) with this function and have that plot globally available outside of the function.
Using the following doesn't work:
paste(map,df1,sep="_") <- get_googlemap(center="Milwaukee") %>% ggmap()+
        stat_density2d(data=df1, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, fill=..density..),geom='tile', contour=F, alpha=.5)+
    labs(fill="seizure density")+
    scale_fill_viridis(option="inferno")


I think you are after assign.
createMap <- function(df1) {
  
  map <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point()
  
  name <- paste("map", deparse(substitute(df1)), sep="_")
  assign(name, map, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

createMap(mtcars)

map_mtcars




create_plot <- function(df) {
  df_name <- deparse(substitute(df))
  ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point()+
    labs(title = df_name, x = "X-axis", y = "Y-axis")


Sorry - my question was confusing; edited.  I'm trying to name the plot itself dynamically - not the title.  In other words, dynamically assigning the name of the variable that stores the plot .
